# ASP.NET web app not deploying correctly on Windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, deployment, teamcity, .net-4.5, windows-server-2012

So here's the thing. I recently updated a web project to use nuget for its dependencies, which in turn updated all of those dependencies to the latest versions.

Quite a task as there were some breaking changes, but I have the thing running locally perfectly.

We use TeamCity to pull the solution from bitbucket and deploy it the the local iis folder on a development (staging) server.

After a build, the website seems very poorly, first off it complains:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\web\Dev.Pegfect.Presentation\bin\mscorlib.dll' or one of
>   its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

Which is strange since my local copy does not have a copy of mscorlib in its web bin folder. Should be using the GAC? If I remove the dll, I get a new error (some NHibernate issue complaining about reflection). I haven't pursued that since it all seems environmental.

If I copy my local bin folder over the server web bin, it starts to run ok albeit extremely slowly (relative to how it used to).

So, the question "what have you tried" - i am currently installing VS 2012 onto the server and will try building the project from source directly. I am also considering updating TeamCity from v7 to v9.

I could also try to reinstall IIS8.0 on the server.

These are desperate, blind shots in the dark. What would you try?

FWIW the project is targeting .NET 4.5.1 (ANY CPU)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I will leave it here as it might help someone.

So, the project has been building, deploying and running successfully on the server compiled to .NET 4.5.1 with no problem.

The recent packages update moved us from MVC v4 to MVC v5. (amongst other things). Running .NET fix tool suggested 4.5.1 was corrupted, so I downloaded the developer version and installed and now its fine.